# How do I set NTFS permissions to a Linux equivalent using Bash on Windows-10?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, windows-10, chmod

I want to remote in to a Ubuntu server using my new and still shiny Windows 10 Bash.  When I try

```
ssh -i "... /private1.ppk" Uname@IP
```

I get the message

> " WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!" & "Permissions 0444 for '...
>   /private1.ppk' are too open."

Wanderings around the web suggest 0600 should do it.

I have already stripped back the permissions for the file private1.ppk and the folder it is in to 'read-only' for just one user. Needless to say

```
chmod 0600 private1.ppk
```

doesn't work. I'm not surprised because the Win & Linux ways are so different but it's worth asking in case I'm missing something ... is there a way to get my file to 0600?

[image: Here's how the permissions look in the Bash shell: -]

In the meantime it's back to PuTTY :-)

Comment: Have I put this question in the wrong place, added the wrong tags or am I just too bleeding edge :-) ?

Comment: I think permission hasn't been implemented yet.